# MongoDuplicateKeyException

Tags: php, mongodb

I have a unique index in MongoDB. When I insert the same data twice (which is wrong), PHP gives a fatal error - why? I just want it give a warning error.

When it gives the fatal error, all execution stops and gives:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'MongoDuplicateKeyException' with
>   message 'localhost:27017: E11000 duplicate key error collection:
>   wcities_social.test index: id_1 dup key: { : null }' in
>   /var/www/html/all/mongo/mongo/test.php:20 Stack trace: #0
>   /var/www/html/all/mongo/mongo/test.php(20):
>   MongoCollection->insert(Array) #1 {main} thrown in
>   /var/www/html/all/mongo/mongo/test.php on line 20;

Comment: Please try to improve your question by adding the affected code. Take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please format and post the question

Comment: Hi dev, and welcome to Stack Overflow. I have edited your question to make the wording a bit more readable, but feel free to [edit] your question further - on this site you are encouraged to edit your questions to improve them as much as possible. Good luck!

Comment: Fatal errors are fatal and terminate execution. There is no way around this if a fatal error occurs.

Answer (score 1):

Write a catch block for MongoDuplicateKeyException, so that you can send personalized message as a warning.

Answer (score 0):

By looking into your error trace in the question.
You are trying to insert a document with a duplicate _id.

_id should be unique in a collection. Insert document with a non existing _id on the collection then your query will be successful.

Refer [this document](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongoduplicatekeyexception.php) for more info MongoDuplicateKeyException

Comment: sorry sir you not understanding what i am try to say. My problem is why give fatal error .any way to give only warning error. and code not execute.